# Is there any short and simple way to write the lengthy where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is code

```
DECLARE @List TABLE (n nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @list (n) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');

SELECT 
  (t1.n ) 
  + (t2.n) 
  + (t3.n) 
  + (t4.n) 
  +(t5.n) 
FROM @list AS t1
JOIN @list AS t2 
    ON 1=1
JOIN @list AS t3 
    ON 1=1
JOIN @list AS t4 
    ON 1=1
JOIN @list AS t5 
    ON 1=1 
WHERE
    not  t1.n = t2.n 
    and not t1.n = t3.n  
    and not t1.n = t4.n 
    and not t1.n = t5.n
    and not t2.n = t3.n  
    and not t2.n = t4.n 
    and not t2.n = t5.n
    and not t3.n = t4.n 
    and not t3.n = t5.n
    and not t4.n = t5.n
```

I need to simplify the where clause like **(where T1.n,T2.n,T3.n,.T4.n,T5.n is not equl to each other)**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create combinations (or is it permutations?), you can use a CTE.

eg:

```
;with cte as
(
select n from @list
union all
select convert(nvarchar(50),L.n+ cte.n) from @List L 
    inner join cte on charindex(l.n,cte.n)=0
where LEN(l.n)<5

)
    select * from cte where LEN(n)=5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check how many distinct values you have:

```
where (
  select count(distinct n)
  from (values (t1.n), (t2.n), (t3.n), (t4.n), (t5.n)) as ns (n)
) = 5
```

If you have less than 5 distinct values, some of the values were equal.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4041/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use,

`NOT IN (....)` clause

Like,

```
where t1.n NOT IN (t2.n, t3.n, t4.n,  t5.n)
and   t2.n NOT IN (t3.n , t4.n,t5.n)
and   t3.n NOT IN  (t4.n,t5.n)
```

Comment: Thanks for help I got the idea where t1.n NOT IN (t2.n, t3.n, t3.n, t4.n, t5.n)
and t2.n not in (t3.n, t4.n, t5.n)
and t3.n not in (t4.n, t5.n) 
and t4.n not in (t5.n) but still it might make more shorter